# Why do `mut` and non-`mut` referrence fields have different lifetimes when returned from a getter?

Tags: rust, lifetime

The code example below seems to be showing that the lifetimes of `mut` and non-`mut` reference field are different. Is that intended?

This code compiles successfully.

```rust
struct Foo<'a> {
    data: &'a u32,
}

impl<'a> Foo<'a> {
    fn foo(&self) -> &'a u32 {
        self.data
    }
}
```

However, after adding `mut` to the `data` field, it fails due to a lifetime problem.

```rust
struct Foo<'a> {
    data: &'a mut u32,
}

impl<'a> Foo<'a> {
    fn foo(&self) -> &'a u32 {
        self.data
    }
}
```

```
error[E0312]: lifetime of reference outlives lifetime of borrowed content...
  --> src/main.rs:10:9
   |
10 |         self.data
   |         ^^^^^^^^^
   |
note: ...the reference is valid for the lifetime 'a as defined on the impl at 8:6...
  --> src/main.rs:8:6
   |
8  | impl<'a> Foo<'a> {
   |      ^^
note: ...but the borrowed content is only valid for the anonymous lifetime #1 defined on the method body at 9:5
  --> src/main.rs:9:5
   |
9  | /     fn foo(&self) -> &'a u32 {
10 | |         self.data
11 | |     }
   | |_____^
```

Why didn't the non-mut version of `self.data` have lifetime of `anonymous lifetime #1` as well?

(BTW, changing `fn foo(&self)` to `fn foo(&'a self)` will compile, but  still, why does the non-`mut` version compiles without this change?)